# XSD required element within xs:choice

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am having a trouble building a schema that will validate sequential required elements followed by randomly ordered optional elements.

This XML snippet is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<messageExample>
  <oprionalField1>3</oprionalField1>
  <requiredField1>1234</requiredField1>
  <requiredField2>WHA_12345678</requiredField2>
  <oprionalField2/>
</messageExample>
```

And the XSD schema for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="messageExample">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="oprionalField1" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int" default="0" />
          <xs:element name="requiredField1" minOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="requiredField2" minOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="oprionalField2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I need to use `<xs:choice>` because by default schema waits message nodes in order listed in schema.

When I pass empty `requredField1` like: `<requiredField1></requiredField>` everything works fine: it throws an exception during validation. But, in case this field is skipped (no `<requiredField1>` tags presented), exception is not thrown.

How can I fix this situation? I want to have an exception if parameter is missed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `<xs:all>` instead of `<xs:choise>`. It forks for me fine.
Example of the xsd schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="messageExample">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="oprionalField1" minOccurs="0" type="xs:int" default="0" />
          <xs:element name="requiredField1" minOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="requiredField2" minOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="oprionalField2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:all>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: This is not well-formed.  Your `<xs:choice>` tag is not closed.  There is a closing tag for `xs:sequence` that was never opened, and if it is supposed to close `<xs:choice>` it is in the wrong level of the document.  In any case, choice is not a valid child for all!  There is no way this could ever work!